# php post json to remote server and get json result

Tags: php, json, curl

i would like to post json data to remote url, and the url will return json format data. here is my code:

```
    $post_array=Array(
    "trips"=>array(
        "departure_code"=> "SIN",
        "arrival_code"=> "HKT",
        "outbound_date"=>"2014-02-29",
        "inbound_date"=> "2014-03-05"
        ),
        "adults_count"=> 1
    );

    $content = json_encode($post_array);
    $curl = curl_init($search_url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $result     = curl_exec($curl);
    //$response   = json_decode($result);
    var_dump($result);
    curl_close($curl);
```

The results should be:

```
{
  "id": "pNQFapkhRQ6ZYxql4MQDbQ",
  "key": "[SIN:HKT:2014-01-29:2014-02-05]~1~0~XX~FI",
  "trips": [
    {
        "id": "SIN:HKT:2014-01-29:2014-02-05",
        "departure_code": "SIN",
        "departure_name": "Singapore",
        "trip_type": "standard"
    }
  ],
 "cabin": "economy",
 "adults_count": 1,
}
```

I got `string(35) "{"message":"Problems parsing JSON"}"`  error. Thanks for help.

Comment: Problem is with your request; see http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl

Comment: Are you really using `Array(...` in your first line or `array(...` (lowercase)? Can you show results of `var_dump($content)`?

Comment: hi, i change Array to array, but the results are same. the results of var_dump($content) is string(129) "{"trips":{"departure_code":"SIN","arrival_code":"HKT","outbound_date":"2014-02-29","inbound_date":"2014-03-05"},"adults_count":1}"

Answer (score 0):

what is the $search_url ?
Do you have any documentation for this service ?

Try to change this line:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
```

to:

```
curl_setopt(
    $curl,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array(
        "Content-type: application/json",
        "Content-Length: ".strlen($content)
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm showing you a simple demo of the `cURL`

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                            'Content-Type:application/json',
                                            'Content-Length:'.strlen($data_string)

                                        ));

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$curl_errorno = curl_errno($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```